# MySQL database with NodeJS using TypeORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, typeorm

How can I make a relation between two tables, where the first table is called `users` and the second is called `cars`?

A `user` can have from 0 to infinite `cars`, and a `car` can only have one `user`. I need to make this relation passing ids from `cars` to `users`.

Using NodeJS TypeORM and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use Many-to-one / one-to-many relations . you can check this example and get some idea.  https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations